# Border image style of div tag

Tags: html, css

I want to show image instead of border, it's working fine in chrome and firefox but not work in IE 9. Is anyone know how to do styling for show border image for div, my css code for div tag is :

```
.arrow_down {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    padding: 0px;
    border-style: solid !important;
    left: 10px !important;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 20px;
    border-left: 0px;
    -webkit-border-image: url('../images/down arrow.png') 30 30 stretch; /*Safari 5*/
    -moz-border-image: url('../images/down arrow.png') 64 64 64 64 stretch stretch;
    /*-webkit-border-image: url('../images/down arrow.png') 64 64 64 64 stretch stretch;*/
    -o-border-image: url('../images/down arrow.png') 12 0 12 30 stretch; /* Opera */
   border-image: url('/images/down arrow.png') 30 30 stretch;

}
```

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: border images are supported from IE11: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image - Maybe you could style a pseudoelement instead

Comment: yeah I checked that, but any other way to show border image

Comment: Can you use a container element slightly bigger in dimension and give background to the container element so that when you see, it looks like you have an image as border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border-image property is not supported by IE, check: http://caniuse.com/border-image for browser support.

But, css3pie can make it possible for you to use a border-image in IE 6-9: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Answer (score 0):

```
border-image: <border-image-source> || <border-image-slice> [ / <border-image-width> | / <border-image-width> ? / <border-image-outset> ]? || <border-image-repeat>
```

**CSS**

```
#box { 
   border: solid 15px;
   border-image: url("border.png") 27 27 round stretch;
}
```

[border-image property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn336997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Update 1:
**DEMO**
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/6w5bs7L3/1/)

**border-image property for all browsers**

```
.cool-border {
width:200px;
height:60px;
padding:10px;
border: 1em double #edb742;
-webkit-border-image: url(border-image-1.png) 30 30 round; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-border-image: url(border-image-1.png) 30 30 round; /* Firefox */
-ms-border-image: url(border-image-1.png) 30 30 round; /* Internet Explorer */
-o-border-image: url(border-image-1.png) 30 30 round; /* Opera */
border-image: url(border-image-1.png) 30 30 round; /* CSS3 */
}
```

Comment: nope, not working. actually i have added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> line in my index.aspx file which support IE 9 settings only, thats why it is not taking border-image style.

Comment: .menu-triangle {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 14px solid white;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    -ms-filter: drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    -o-filter: drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0, OffY=0, Color='

Comment: gray', Positive='true');
} i have added manually shape of triangle to div